# angular-translate - $translate service does only work with promises

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I just upgraded angular-translate from version 1.1.1 to 2.7.2. Before, I was using the $translate service inside JavaScript like for example:

```
alert($translate('login.ACCOUNT_NOT_CONFIRMED'));
```

Now, after the upgrade, this leads to displaying of '{}'.

Inside HTML, using the translate filter or the translate tag attribute still works though.

I am configuring the translation table statically like this:

```
$translateProvider.translations('en', {
    'login.ACCOUNT_NOT_CONFIRMED': 'Your account...',
    ...
});
```

The language is set like this.

```
$translate.use('en');
```

It seems to me, that angular-translate switched to an asynchronous/promise-based programming model. When I use something like this:

```
$translate('login.NOT_SUCCESSFUL').then(function (loginTranslation) {
    alert(loginTranslation);
}
```

then the translation succeeds.

My problem is that I don't need the asynchronity, and I also don't want it in this case, because, compared to before, the code just gets more complicated.

How can I still use the old way of calling

```
$translate('login.ACCOUNT_NOT_CONFIRMED')
```

synchronously and retrieving the translation as return value?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$translate.instant('login.ACCOUNT_NOT_CONFIRMED');
```